# Function of listToArray(function(arrayToList(array)

Tags: javascript

I made this code that turns an array into a list below

```
// This is a function to make a list from an array
// This is a recursive function
function arrayToList(array) {
    // I use an object constructor notation here
    var list = new Object();
    // This is to end the recursion, if array.length == 1, the function won't call itself and instead
    // Just give rest = null
    if (array.length == 1) {
        list.value = array[array.length - 1];
        list.rest = null;
        return list;
    } else {
        // This is to continue the recursion.  If the array.length is not == 1, make the rest key to call arrayToList function
        list.value = array[0];
        // To avoid repetition, splice the array to make it smaller
        array.splice(0,1);
        list.rest = arrayToList(array);
        return list;
    }
}

arrayToList([1, 2]);
```

However, now I am trying to reverse the process, which is to write a function that will return an array from a list.

so I'd like the function to be something like below,

```
listToArray(function(arrayToList([1,2])
=> [1,2]
```

How do I do this, please help?

Comment: Are you saying that you specifically want to use recursion?

Comment: yes I want to use recursion because if the array has elements more than 2, then it will need more steps to revert the list back to array, am I right?

edit: sorry, the coded before provided below, it turns out that I don't need to use recursion. Thank you so much

Comment: Yes, but you don't need recursion to accomplish it. A simple loop as shown in the answer below can handle it easily enough. Just wasn't sure if you specifically wanted a recursive function to accomplish this like you used in `arrayToList()`. EDIT: Looks like you've got it figured out. :-)

Comment: Yes, thats true.  However, do you think it is possible to have arrayToList() without using recursion?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. You just need a `first_item` variable to hold the first item in the list. That's what you'll return when done, so it doesn't change. Then you need a `current_item` variable to hold the current item in the list as you create it. This will start off holding the first item, then every time you create a new item, you add it to the `current_item.rest`, and then change `current_item` to point to the new `current_item.rest`. When done, return the `first_item`.

Comment: ...like this: http://jsfiddle.net/kHJ9y/

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code:

```
function listToArray(list) {
    var array = [];
    var item = list;
    while (item) {
        array.push(item.value);
        item = item.rest;
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, it works! so I don't need to use recursion.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for posting full code, but I do it for purpose of easy comprehension:

```
function arrayToList(arr) {
  var li = {};
  li.value=arr[0], arr.shift();
  if(arr.length) li.rest=arrayToList(arr);
  else li.rest=null; 
  return li;
}
function listToArray(li) {
  var arr = [];
  for(var i=li; i; i=i.rest) arr.push(i.value);
  return arr;
}
function prepend(a, b) {
  var li = {};
  li.value=a, li.rest=b;
  return li;
}
function nth(li, n) {
  var elem, cnt=0;
  for(var i=li; i; i=i.rest, cnt++) {
    if(cnt==n) {
      elem=i.value;
      break;
    }
  }
  return elem;
}

console.log(arrayToList([10, 20]));
// → {value: 10, rest: {value: 20, rest: null}}
console.log(listToArray(arrayToList([10, 20, 30])));
// → [10, 20, 30]
console.log(prepend(10, prepend(20, null)));
// → {value: 10, rest: {value: 20, rest: null}}
console.log(nth(arrayToList([10, 20, 30]), 1));
// → 20
```